# sum of uniformly bounded projections acting on a Lorentz sequence space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

It is known that for every $k\in\mathbb{N}$ there is $N_k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that every $N_k$-dimensional subspace of $\ell_p$, $1<p<\infty$, contains uniformly complemented copies of $\ell_2^k$ (see Theorem 4.10 in [this paper](http://www.math.tamu.edu/~thomas.schlumprecht/ideals_ell_p_ell_q.pdf)).  It is also known that the Lorentz sequence space $d(a,p)$ contains a complemented copy of $\ell_p$ formed from a block basis of the canonical basis $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ of $d(a,p)$.  (Definitions and a lot of nice results on Lorentz sequence spaces can be found in [this paper](http://www.pdf-archive.com/2016/01/01/acl73/acl73.pdf).)

Hence, we could find some uniform constant $C\in[1,\infty)$ such that for each $k\in\mathbb{N}$ there is $N_k\in\mathbb{N}$ and a norm-$C$ projection $P_k:[x_n]_{n=1}^{N_k}\to[x_n]_{n=1}^{N_k}$ onto a $C$-isomorphic copy of $\ell_2^k$.

Now, let's string together these uniformly complemented copies of $\ell_2^k$ in the following way.  We "shift" (and relabel) $P_k$ so that it acts on $[x_n]_{n=M_k+1}^{M_k+N_k}$, where $M_k=\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}N_i$.  Now, let $(v_n^{(k)})_{n=1}^k$ denote the copy of the canonical basis of $\ell_2^k$ sitting in $[x_n]_{n=M_k+1}^{M_k+N_k}$.  Without loss of generality, assume it is normalized.  Note that $\{(v_n^{(k)})_{n=1}^k:k\in\mathbb{N}\}$, now forms a normalized block basic sequence in $d(a,p)$, with each consecutive $k$-long stretch uniformly isomorphic to the $\ell_2^k$ basis, and uniformly complemented in $d(a,p)$.

**My question is:** could the block basic sequence $\{(v_n^{(k)})_{n=1}^k:k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ span a complemented subspace of $d(a,p)$?

It seems plausible since it is formed from uniformly complemented stretches of vectors.  But, the basis of $d(a,p)$ is not always as well-behaved as we might like, so maybe this is not true.

Thank you!